# Moving text from the centre to the left hand side in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to move my text to the left-hand side from the centre. `text-align` or `float` properties don't work.

I know there is a previous question like this but none of the solutions worked. Can anyone see if I am doing anything wrong here? I am using Brackets and here is my code:

```
.logo {
    color: #0000000
    float: left;
    padding-left: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}


.logo > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Here is the .html

```
<ul class="gws">

    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#">LOGO</a>        
    </div>
```

Here is how the website currently looks

http://prntscr.com/k14jf5

Here is the full coding

http://prntscr.com/k1b1zl and http://prntscr.com/k1b2gn

Comment: Submitting little bit more code will be helpful to fixup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: To move Left side use

```
{
 float:right;
 padding-right:50px;
}
```

To move Right side

```
{
float:left;
padding-left:50px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, when I tried it, it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Hex colors contain 6 digits, yours has 7, also do not forget to place a semicolon (`;`) behind the color and the `float: left;` See if that works.

Comment: The hex color does contain six 0's. The semicolon doesn't fix it, I had it there before but I think I might of acciden

Comment: Okay but what about placing a semicolon behind the **first** color rule? And I still count 7 0's in the first color rule. Check again please.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that I would suggest:

1. The **float** is missing the ending semicolon. It should be like this:

   float: left;
2. What's the width of the unordered list class? Make sure it's sufficient to let your logo to align to the left. If it has a fixed width then make it large.

If you could provide more information then I would be able to help better!

Comment: The hex colour does contain six 0's. Also the semi colon doesn't work, I had it there before but I think I might of deleted it accidentially.

Comment: The HEX code you've written here has 7 zeroes. Anyway, have you checked the container width that's containing your logo?

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result you should give `anchor tag` to.

```
.logo { 
    color: #0000000; 
    padding-left: 25px; 
    font-size: 16px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
}

.logo > a { 
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #000000; 
    text-align: left;
}
```